# Master Theorem case 2 - Constant k

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, master-theorem

I'm studying for a midterm on Master Theorem and I came across an example for case 2 where k > 0. I understand everything about the theorem except for the constant and how it increments or is calculated.

[Case 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2) states: T(n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> log<sup>k+1</sup>n) when n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> = f(n) but where does the k come from?

**The example in question:**

Matrix Multiplication

```
cilk void Mult(*C, *A, *B, n) {
    float *T = Cilk_alloca(n*n*sizeof(float));
    spawn Mult(C11,A11,B11,n/2);
    spawn Mult(C12,A11,B12,n/2);
    spawn Mult(C22,A21,B12,n/2);
    spawn Mult(C21,A21,B11,n/2);
    spawn Mult(T11,A12,B21,n/2);
    spawn Mult(T12,A12,B22,n/2);
    spawn Mult(T22,A22,B22,n/2);
    spawn Mult(T21,A22,B21,n/2);
    sync;
    spawn Add(C,T,n);
    sync; 
    return;
}

cilk void Add(*C, *T, n) {
  h base case & partition matrices i
  spawn Add(C11,T11,n/2);
  spawn Add(C12,T12,n/2);
  spawn Add(C21,T21,n/2);
  spawn Add(C22,T22,n/2);
  sync;
  return;
}
```

The span of the addition has been found to be: Θ(log n)

When calculating the span of the multiplication the example states:

M1(n) = M1(n/2) + A1(n) + Θ(1)

A1(n) being Θ(log n) so really: M1(n) = M1(n/2) + Θ(log n)

n log<sub>b</sub>a = n log<sub>2</sub>1 = 1 --> f(n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> log<sup>1</sup> n)

So the span ends up being: Θ(log<sup>2</sup> n).

What I'm wondering is why is k = 1 in this example?

Comment: The `k` appears in the conditions, `f(n) \in Theta(n^log_b a * log^k n)`.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question to contain the question I was referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **find** such parameter `k` so that the expression `Θ(nlogbalogkn)` will be `Θ(log n)`. In this case `k=1` will satisfy the requirement. It's a matching you need to do in order to get the required form of the expression. More specifically, it's similar to solving an equation `logkn = log n` for `k`.

Comment: I think you need to find parameter k so that the resulting expression will be O(nlogn) and not O(logn) ?